# Overlay two stat_function in a single plot, but with different length of x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the below chart:

[image]

below is my attempt, colors and labels would be fine_tuned, just showing the problem here. Trying to be straight forward to with the second stat_function's x values limited to (0.28,0.30), whereas the first stat_function having a longer x values (0.28, 0.32).

```r
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_light())
alpha_single <- 3850
beta_single <- 8818
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0.28,0.32)), aes(x))+
  stat_function(fun = dbeta, args = list(shape1 = alpha_single, shape2 = beta_single))+
  stat_function(data = data.frame(x=c(0.28,0.3)), aes(x),fun = dbeta, args = list(shape1 = alpha_single, shape2 = beta_single), geom = "area", fill = "blue", inherit.aes = F)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9000)</sup>

Not sure how ggplot interpreted this. Any pointer would be appreciated.

Grateful if anyone can show me how do what I intended with stat_function. That would help me finally understand how stat_function works. I believe I can do this with a more iterative approach, where I would generate data.frame(s) and plot them with different geom(s). but just to understand why this more straightforward way wouldn't work? how come the blue just filled everything?

Comment: Try `stat_function(xlim = c(0.28,0.3), aes(x),fun = dbeta, args = list(shape1 = alpha_single, shape2 = beta_single), geom = "area", fill = "blue", inherit.aes = F)` as your last `stat_function()` call. The important bit is the `xlim`. The `data` argument are the values that the stat is calculated on, but the function is calculated over the entire range of all x-values in the panel (unless the xlim is set).

Comment: It seems it could be answered with [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753007/using-stat-function-to-draw-partially-shaded-normal-curve-in-ggplot2]

Comment: @teunbrand great! your solution works! Many thanks! if you could post it as an answer, I shall definitely accept it!

Comment: @iago thank for the pointers. The answers to the linked question really taught me how stat_function works under the hood. but when I was searching for similar questions it didn't pop up. I guess it is because overlaying two stat_function had only been proposed as an alternative in the adopted answer, albeit a very good explanation.